# How to display popup to confirm before add to cart in magento 2?

Tags: magento, magento2

I want to show a popup when a user first click on the button "add to cart". The popup will show please choose the inventory source. Example in my stock have inventory source INS-1 and INS-2. The user choose the inventory source (ex: INS-1) I will save it on the cookie. When user click on the "Confirm" button. I will check the product sale able in that inventory source before add to shopping cart.
Example: user choose INS-1 check product is sale able in INS-1. If product can salable then add product to cart. Else show the message "The product cannot sale able".

I create an observer can check the product salable by inventory source when the user click on add to cart button. But I don't know how to call that observer after user click confirm button instead click add to cart button. and I don't know how to prevent add to cart button before user click confirm button on the popup.

Please help me, How to do that?

Thank you so much,
BienHV